# Text to Path in metro style app

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

Can i convert a text to path in metro style app? I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743610%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). But it seems `FormattedText` is not available in metro.

Comment: Which framework are you using? The HTML+JS, C++, etc?

Comment: C# with XAML (marked in tags)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this in code in a Metro style application, you could use something like [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) to manually create tha path (Inkscape can save to xaml paths) which you can use instead of text.

Comment: There is already an option in Blend for creating path manually. But it won't work for me. I need to generate text path at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need? What is your purpose? You can use FolderPicker as follow. And then you will get file path from FolderPicker object.

```
FolderPicker saveFolder = new FolderPicker();                
saveFolder.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;                
saveFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder storagefolderSave = await saveFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

If above code doesn't match with your necessary, show me some parts of your code and your purpose. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry, i think you misunderstood my question, i'm talking about **Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path** , not about  **System.IO.Path**